# Invalid character constant in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

My webapp throws this error:

```
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /pages/workbench/user/taskassessmentexample.jsp
taskassessmentexample.jsp:204:230: Invalid character constant
                                                    String message = "<b>" + riskNote.getUser() + "</b> (<span style=\"font-size:80%\">" + riskNote.getDisplayTimeStamp() + "</span> ) :&nbsp; <span style=\"font-style:italic;\">" + riskNote.getMessage().replaceAll(&apos;\n&apos;,&apos;<br/>&apos;) + "</span><br/>";
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^----^

    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.reportCompilationErrorIfNeccessary(JavelinxJSPStub.java:226)
```

The JSP that generates it is:

```
String message = "<b>" + riskNote.getUser() + "</b> (<span style=\"font-size:80%\">" + riskNote.getDisplayTimeStamp() + "</span> ) :&nbsp; <span style=\"font-style:italic;\">" + riskNote.getMessage().replaceAll('\n','<br/>') + "</span><br/>";
out.println(message);
```

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: how about `replaceAll("\n","<br/>")` with double quote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have seen a compilation error at:

```
... replaceAll('\n','<br/>') ...
```

because these arguments should be strings enclosed in double quotes:

```
... replaceAll("\n", "<br/>") ...
```